# Error when creating word document with ASP

Tags: asp.net, windows, ms-word

i am new to asp. I have an error when the application try to create a word document. 
This happens sometimes, in different machines and some users and I can't get to reproduce in testing environment (Only in production). 
And at my workplace is very limited what I can try without asking to production area.

This is the error:

```
SCRIPT4605: este comando no está disponible para la lectura Este método o propiedad no está disponible porque.

Translation: This command is not available for reading. This method or property is not avaiable
```

I look for the error in production environment and it seems to be in these five lines, when trying to create a grid and insert a barcode(The creation of the barcode works fine).

```
Set myRange = objDoc.Range(0, 0)
    Set myTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(myRange, 1, 1)
    Set myCell = myTable.Cell(1, 1)
    myCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
    myCell.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "<%=archivo_temporal%>"
```

So, the objDoc is created fine, but its seems that does not have (It depends in the user and the machine) the Range() method.

Here is the entire function.

```
Sub OpenDoc(strLocation)

    Dim iOut
    Dim oElement
    Dim objWord
    Dim doc


    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = true
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strLocation)



    codigo_barras_b64 = DecodeString("<%=codigo_barras_b64%>")

    set FSObj = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
    set file = FSObj.CreateTextFile("<%=archivo_temporal%>", true)          
    file.write (codigo_barras_b64)    
    set file = nothing




    Set myRange = objDoc.Range(0, 0)
    Set myTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(myRange, 1, 1)
    Set myCell = myTable.Cell(1, 1)
    myCell.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
    myCell.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "<%=archivo_temporal%>"



    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Secretaria", "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "secreDescrip"))%> ")'
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Autos", "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeAutos"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Sobre", "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeSobre"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("En",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeEn"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Juez",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "juezNombres"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("ExpNro",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeNro"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Fecha",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "fechaInicio"))%> ")

    objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs "c:\temp\tsj.doc" 
    objWord.Application.Activate



    ' Borra el archivo generado 
    Set MyFile = FSObj.GetFile("<%=archivo_temporal%>")
    MyFile.Delete

    set FSObj = nothing 
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is anyway that I can insert the barcode in a different way to avoid these lines?
Someone have an idea why this error?
Some hints to look around?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Try `objDoc.Content` instead of the `Range` method to set `myRange`.

Comment: if I change   Set myRange = objDoc.Range(0, 0) with   Set myRange = objDoc.Content  only appear the barcode, but the rest of documents is blank.

Comment: perhaps i can add the barcode in another way or with different logic. I am reading the documentation of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application but it uses the Range method.

Comment: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Comment: I changed the code  mentioned above for this code (Does the same without the Range method) :

   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
   objSelection.TypeText (vbCrLf & "funca?....")
   Set objShapes = objDoc.InlineShapes
   objShapes.AddPicture ("<%=archivo_temporal%>")
But i can't center the picture. 
I tried with    objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter But doesn't work.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to put the code *in the question* - it's more or less unreadable in a comment. And to let someone know you're answering them you need to *ping* them using @, for example @MrGuiles.