# Insert and center image in document with Visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some code that insert an image in a word document.

```
   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
   Set objShapes = objDoc.InlineShapes
   objShapes.AddPicture ("<%=archivo_temporal%>")
```

Is any way that I can center the image?
I tried with 
  objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

But it doesn't work.

He is the entire code:

```
Sub OpenDoc(strLocation)

    Dim iOut
    Dim oElement
    Dim objWord
    Dim doc


    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = true
    objword.Activate 

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strLocation)

    codigo_barras_b64 = DecodeString("<%=codigo_barras_b64%>")

    set FSObj = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

    set file = FSObj.CreateTextFile("<%=archivo_temporal%>", true)          
    file.write (codigo_barras_b64)    
    set file = nothing

   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
   objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
   Set objShapes = objDoc.InlineShapes
   objShapes.AddPicture ("<%=archivo_temporal%>")  




    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Secretaria", "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "secreDescrip"))%> ")'
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Autos", "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeAutos"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Sobre", "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeSobre"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("En",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeEn"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Juez",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "juezNombres"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("ExpNro",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "expeNro"))%> ")
    iOut = objword.ActiveDocument.Variables.Add("Fecha",  "<%=sLimpiarTextArea(sValor(RSCarat, "fechaInicio"))%> ")

    objWord.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
    objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs "c:\temp\tsj.doc" 
    objWord.Application.Activate



    ' Borra el archivo generado 
    Set MyFile = FSObj.GetFile("<%=archivo_temporal%>")
    MyFile.Delete

    set FSObj = nothing 
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: A great secret for inserting inline shapes is to put them in a single cell table.

Comment: Did the suggestions by macropod help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when creating word document with ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653474/error-when-creating-word-document-with-asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, replace:

```
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

with:

```
objWord.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

Alternatively, you might replace:

```
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
Set objShapes = objDoc.InlineShapes
objShapes.AddPicture ("<%=archivo_temporal%>")
```

with:

```
Set objShapes = objDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture ("<%=archivo_temporal%>")  
objShapes.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```